# LPG tank leaking even when valve is closed

Tags: propane

I have two LPG cylinders, the first one is 2 years old and the second is brand new.  When I hook either one or the other to my BBQ they leak even when the valve is closed.

Do you believe my BBQ regulator is the problem? If so, how can a faulty regulator make a closed cylinder leak?

Comment: What valve is closed and the tanks leak?  Where is the leak occurring?

Comment: @FKEinternet The cylinder valve is closed but gas still flows in the BBQ lines. Gaz is stopped just before the BBQ burners because the BBQ control knobs are all closed.

Comment: I'm trying to picture how this works.  On *my* grill, there's a valve on the propane tank.  I close that valve, and the gas to the grill is shut off.  Is that the valve that you say is leaking?  If so, the cylinder would leak when it's disconnected from the grill.  If that is *not* the valve you are talking about, maybe you should attach a picture to your question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: If the valve on the LPG cylinder leaks it must be replaced or repaired.